# PHP Composer Not Working On Mac

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I have installed a bitnami mac stack mainly because I require at least PHP 5.4.7 version for my project. However, I have run into an issue with composer. This is the error I get when I run:

```
php composer.phar install --dev
```

The error:

```
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:my-project richardknop$ php composer.phar install --dev
dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/php
  Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Trace/BPT trap
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:my-project richardknop$
```

How to solve it?

Comment: This is more of an IT problem no? Perhaps serverfault would be better?

Comment: @thatidiotguy serverfault is definitely _not_ the right place for this.  They will most definitely just close the question.

Comment: @mmmshuddup Alrighty. It just reads like more of a missing library then a coding question. Their FAQ states: "Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, _software_ and virtualization". Whatever OP thinks is best; my apologies.

Comment: Indeed this doesn't seem to have anything to do with composer. It seems your system (or MAMP's) iconv is out of date compared to what php requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your mamp installation the error clearly says that your libiconv.2.dylib is outdated.

If MAMP has no more-to-date version install apache + php via. mac-ports.

Answer (score 1):

BitNami is self-contained and doesn't modify your system environment. I think that the problem was that the BitNami environment was not loaded.

> Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/php

That doesn't seem to belong to a BitNami installation. For future reference the solution (I think) would have been:

- Load the BitNami environment executing `/Application/mampstack-5.4.x/use_mampstack`
- After that make sure that the environment is loaded correctly executing `which php`
- Then execute `php composer.phar install --dev`